# Работа с формами с помощью AJAX и POST запросов в Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Работаю с Django. Написал парсер, который собирает подписчиков в инстаграме. Парсер запускается на сайте при вводе в форму желаемый username.
То есть ввели username, отправили форму, в функции во views получили введенный username и передали параметром в функцию парсера. Понятно, что пока парсер работает, идёт перезагрузка страницы, так как request.POST. Хочу сделать с помощью ajax. Как передавать так же username через форму, но при этом, чтобы работало ajax'om? Я написал программу, но она не работает. Уверен, что там косяки, но представлю свой код, чтобы вы поняли, что именно я хотел бы сделать.

**base html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% block script %}{% endblock %}

</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'authapp/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'scripts/parser-ajax.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ unloading_list_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn_get_followers">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

---

В этой функции мне нужно получить username_data, чтобы передать параметром в parser.get_followers()

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import UnloadingListForm

# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        unloading_list_form = UnloadingListForm(request.POST)
        if unloading_list_form.is_valid():
            if request.is_ajax():
                username_data = request.GET.get('username', None)
                parser = Parser()
                parser.get_followers(username_data)

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authapp:login'))
    else:
        unloading_list_form = UnloadingListForm()

    content = {
        'unloading_list_form': unloading_list_form
    }

    return render(request, 'authapp/login.html', content)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class UnloadingList(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import UnloadingList


class UnloadingListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UnloadingList
        fields = ['username']
```

**parser-ajax.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('.btn_get_followers').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login/',
            type: 'post',
            success: function () {
                alert('Сбор завершен.');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
import authapp.views as authapp

app_name = 'authapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', authapp.login, name='login')
]
```

Comment: на каком именно этапе у вас не работает? и что именно не работает, опишите проблему. `if request.is_ajax():` не нужно, вместо `username_data = request.GET.get('username', None)` нужно `username = unloading_list_form.cleaned_data['username']`, нелогично при post запросы пытаться найти в get параметры. `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authapp:login'))` куда должен идти редирект, если вы хотите не перезагружать страницу? вам нужно отрендерить результат валидации формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .forms import UnloadingListForm
from authapp.management.scripts.parser import Parser
from .models import UserFollowersList


# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    unloading_list_form = UnloadingListForm()

    content = {
        'unloading_list_form': unloading_list_form
    }

    return render(request, 'authapp/login.html', content)


def get_followers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']

        parser = Parser()
        driver = parser.init_driver()
        profile_users = parser.get_followers(driver, username)

        for profile_user in profile_users:
            user_followers_list = UserFollowersList(follower_name=profile_user)
            user_followers_list.save()

        driver.quit()

        return HttpResponse('')
```

**parser-ajax.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('.btn_get_followers').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/get_followers/',
            data: {
                username: $('#id_username').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log('done');
                alert('DONE');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**urls.py в папке самого приложения**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import authapp.views as authapp

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('authapp.urls', namespace='auth')),
    path('get_followers/', authapp.get_followers, name='get_followers')
]
```